# Sum of mixed values in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, dictionary

Could you please help me to find the sum of values from the following dictionary?

```
fun= dict(a=1, b='xyz', c=10, d='rst',e=10)
```

My work:

```
isinstance(fun['b'],(int, float))

t=sum(fun.values())

print(t)
```

I am interested to use for loop here. I have tried using the `sum()` function but it didn't work due to the presence of string values.

Comment: What do you want as a result? To find the total number of values in a dictionary?

Comment: Define “sum of values.” You have both strings and integers present, which default to string operations.

Comment: I was looking for the sum of values of key a, c,e. Output should be 21. JerryM.

Comment: @Hasibul How do we turn a, c, and e into values?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean sum of only `int` and `float` values:

```
>>> sum(value for value in fun.values() if isinstance(value, (int, float)))
21
```

Comment: @Hasibul You are welcome! Your question is ambiguous, it is not clear sum of what values you exactly want.

Comment: I was looking for the sum of values of key a, c,e. Output should be 21. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter`:

```py
sum(filter(lambda x : isinstance(x, (int, float)), fun.values()))
# output: 21
```

Comment: Why did you use lamda function here? Could you please explain?

Comment: @Hasibul It has the same effect as a `for` loop with a `judgement`. check https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your time.